# Youtube-dl Automator service in Yosemite

Tags: macos, service, automator, youtube-dl

Automator service
Service receives selected:URLs in Safari

Run Shell Script
Shell: /bin/bash Pass input:to stdin

```
cd ~/Downloads
for f in "$@"
do
youtube-dl -x "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --all-subs --max-quality "$f"
done
```

youtube-dl and ffdshow installed via curl

Working in Mavericks but after I upgraded into Yosemite its putting a Shell Script error.

Comment: Is everyone supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: Here is the message: The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your invocation of youtube-dl is extremely strange and almost certainly erroneous. As it stands, you're always downloading the URL `"%(title)s.%(ext)s"`. You want

```
youtube-dl -x -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --all-subs -- "$f"
```